# Shopware lower case urls not works

Tags: php, mysql, shopware

I have shopware 5.2.22.

When I rebuild URLs with 'Use only lower case letters in URLs' set to 'yes', the URLs are still uppercase.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Mind if you show us the offending code?

Comment: Sorry I can't show you any code ( Because I think it's a bug in CMS, so this function does't work. Now I looking the problem in the code

Comment: This is a programming website, so if you have no code to show, it is unlikely to get a lot of good answers